# Одинокий вариативный товар не удаляется с мини корзины

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет. Есть у меня магазин на wordpress+woocomerce и такая беда с его мини-корзиной: при добавлении одиночного товара в корзину (используется ajax) кнопка удаления формируется следующим образом:

```
<a href="../cart-2/?remove_item=6dfe08eda761bd321f8a9b239f6f4ec3&amp;_wpnonce=2f109f3425" class="remove-item" title="Удалить эту позицию">remove</a>
```

если товар добавляется 1 в единственном экземпляре, то [wpnonce](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nonce_url) каждый раз равняется числу 2f109f3425 , хотя фактически в самой корзине отличается и равен к примеру **wpnonce=6395b5dd32** (кроме раздела по категориям - там все гуд. баг возникает только на главной и странице товара). Если добавить несколько товаров в корзину или больше, чем 1 штуку одного наименования **wpnonce** считает каждый раз правильно.

**После последнего обновления woocommerce для стандартных товаров баг исчез!**
но для вариативных товаров он по прежнему присутствует..сама проблема кроется в ajax, т.к. при отключении плагина ajax добавления в корзину вариативного товара баг уходит. Никто не может подсказать почему так происходит? Для сравнения [ссылка на гит вариативного](https://github.com/wp-plugins/woocommerce-ajax-add-to-cart-for-variable-products/blob/master/js/add-to-cart-variation.js) [ссылка на гит простого](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/d0c2c10c472af3ea79d732a12fed98d67ce3d34b/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js)

Comment: Судя по коду разные варианты отправляют свои запросы по разным адресам: вариативный шлет запрос в `wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url`, простой в `wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart' )`. И вы сами можете посмотреть в браузере, включив инструменты разработчика (сеть), куда уходят запросы в том и другом случаях, и чем отличаются отправленные данные.

Comment: @Visman сделать одинаковые, но к сожалению, это ничего не дало.. Зашел на вкладку network -А как я могу увидеть различия и отличия? где смотреть?

Comment: В современных браузерах есть инструменты разработчика, в инструментах есть средство отслеживания запросов браузера. Например в FF вызывается по Ctrl+Shift+Q, в результате можно видеть заголовки и содержимое запросов.

Comment: @Visman так а что мне это дает? в первом и втором случае срабатывает событие вида `?remove_item=48d9766134a20c63e92155197e071254&_wpnonce=fcedcac60b`, которые отличаются концовкой `fcedcac60b` что я итак знал..

Comment: Почему вы тогда не можете отследить, где у вас формируется _wpnonce?

Comment: @Visman я не знаю  -а как ее отследить? - в подключаемом плагине ее нет..